# Puppet conditional include based on selinux fact not working

Tags: linux, centos, puppet

I have a class in a module:

```
# File: modules/selinux/tools.pp
class selinux::tools {
        $packages = ['policycoreutils-python',]

        package { $packages:
                ensure => installed
        }
}
```

Then, my default node:

```
# File: manifests/nodes/default.pp
node default {
        if $selinux {
                include selinux::tools
        }
}
```

I restart `puppetmaster` and the `puppet` agent. However, the package gets installed in the node even though the `selinux` fact is false:

```
$ facter -p selinux
false
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "true" or "false" in the `selinux` fact is just a string to Puppet, it doesn't treat the contents of the string as a boolean.  The correct thing to do is just to compare it to another string:

```
if $selinux == "true" {
    include selinux::tools
}
```

[There is a feature request](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/3704) to change the behavior so that Facter booleans are properly treated as Puppet booleans.

Comment: Is [this](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/variables.html#if) mis-documentation then?

Comment: It works! Thanks. Still, according to [their documentation](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/learning/variables.html#if), at least some facts are interpreted as bool values. How would I know which are strings and which are bool?

Comment: Nope - I think that documentation is wrong. Try it for yourself - even 'false' would come up as a positive.

Comment: Agreed, though it sort of gives the reasoning in the next section.  I've filed [#11183](http://projects.puppetlabs.com/issues/11183) as I think the example deserves a big warning and to properly compare how the variable should be tested.